# Creating a categorical variable for a dataframe based on column value

Tags: r, dataframe, encoding

I have a dataframe created in R that is organized as follows:

```
> all_data[3945:3952,]
           Date btc_close eth_close vix_close gold_close DEXCHUS
3945 2016-11-01    729.27     10.77     18.56     122.73     828
3946 2016-11-02    742.46        NA     19.32     123.64     826
3947 2016-11-03    687.51        NA     22.08     124.30     827
3948 2016-11-04    702.54        NA     22.51     124.39     824
3949 2016-11-05    704.16        NA        NA         NA      NA
3950 2016-11-06    712.24        NA        NA         NA      NA
3951 2016-11-07    704.02        NA     18.71     122.15     835
3952 2016-11-08    709.15     10.87     18.74     121.64     843
```

How can I add a new column that has 3 levels? The levels would be -1 for decrease, 0 for no change, and 1 for increase. This `direction` column should be based upon the previous days value for `btc_close`.
(Note- there will be many NA's- I would then like to subset the data according to only rows that have data for `btc_close`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After dropping NA rows, you could do

```
dat$change <- c(0, sign(diff(dat$btc_close)))
```

for this example, you'd get

```
dat
           Date btc_close eth_close vix_close gold_close DEXCHUS change
3945 2016-11-01    729.27     10.77     18.56     122.73     828      0
3946 2016-11-02    742.46        NA     19.32     123.64     826      1
3947 2016-11-03    687.51        NA     22.08     124.30     827     -1
3948 2016-11-04    702.54        NA     22.51     124.39     824      1
3949 2016-11-05    704.16        NA        NA         NA      NA      1
3950 2016-11-06    712.24        NA        NA         NA      NA      1
3951 2016-11-07    704.02        NA     18.71     122.15     835     -1
3952 2016-11-08    709.15     10.87     18.74     121.64     843      1
```

**data**

```
dat <- 
structure(list(Date = structure(1:8, .Label = c("2016-11-01", 
"2016-11-02", "2016-11-03", "2016-11-04", "2016-11-05", "2016-11-06", 
"2016-11-07", "2016-11-08"), class = "factor"), btc_close = c(729.27, 
742.46, 687.51, 702.54, 704.16, 712.24, 704.02, 709.15), eth_close = c(10.77, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10.87), vix_close = c(18.56, 19.32, 22.08, 
22.51, NA, NA, 18.71, 18.74), gold_close = c(122.73, 123.64, 
124.3, 124.39, NA, NA, 122.15, 121.64), DEXCHUS = c(828L, 826L, 
827L, 824L, NA, NA, 835L, 843L)), .Names = c("Date", "btc_close", 
"eth_close", "vix_close", "gold_close", "DEXCHUS"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("3945", 
"3946", "3947", "3948", "3949", "3950", "3951", "3952"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following strategy. You can compare values in btc_closed column/attribute across your table using ifelse. Remember to add a NA value (or a 0 if you prefer) since you start to compare from row 2.

```
df <- data.frame(btc_close = c(223, 222, 224, 224, 223, 223, 224), stuff = NA) 
df$direction <- c(NA, (sapply(2:nrow(df), (function(i){
  ifelse(df$btc_close[i] > df$btc_close[(i-1)], 1, 
         ifelse(df$btc_close[i] < df$btc_close[(i-1)], -1, 0))}))))
```